# wrong scheduling date

Tags: rules

I have put this code into my scheduler under php evaluation. It gives me wrong output like:
Thu, 01/01/1970 - 05:30

My Code:
I put a cck field in data selector to get the date value that I am using in $value variable to get the date.

```
$originalDate = $value;
$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $originalDate);
return date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+3 days"));
```

Please help me why its printing the wrong date in scheduler.

Screen short of my scheduler page what i am trying to do is.. may be it will be more helpful to understand

[image]

Comment: just a suggestion.
why don't you use a data selector as a CCK field and then Add offset 3 days? Because I also wanted to schedule my event to trigger when the cck field date value equals to the current date.And it worked for me.

Comment: i can't use offset bcause ihave a another form where user can set his alerts and reminder. as if he set alert before 3 days then i will get that cck field value and set the scheduler accordingly. its not a fix value to use in offset.

Comment: it a cck field value that is used as data selector.

Comment: same above code if i used in identifier for testing purpose its displaying the correct result. I don't know why its not working in php evaluation part.

Comment: Please tell us what is in `$originalDate = $value;`.

Comment: here i want to get cck field value that i used in data selector. I am assuming its automatically pick the value that we put in data selector. I am not sure is it  write or wrong. may be the main problem is here $value variable is not getting the exact value.

Comment: I am not sure but I tried to get the field value in code and your $value is a timestmap not an actual date.
So if you can just change
$originalDate = date("Y-m-d",$value);

return date('Y-m-d',strtotime($originalDate . "+3 days"));

Comment: Well you can do one thing in this case:

Add a new CCK field which can be only seen by admin user.(This will be used for your calculation of date).

Once the node is created,you can call a theme_preprocess_field function and calculate using the above code which you do in Rules Configuration. Set the calculated date value for the NEW FIELD created. And use the same date directly into the Rules. you won't have to calculate in rules in this case.

Comment: can you please tell me the value that i selected in data selector (can check in attached screen short) can called with $value variable automatically?

Comment: Thanks Aniruddh.. Your idea works.. :) Thank you so much.